# Powershell: Get-Item vs Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

I would like understand the difference between `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem`. 
If is possible with one example.

Comment: I see that you just signed up with StackOverflow today and this is your first question. I do suggest you [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site and look into how to ask good questions. You're currently getting down-voted because your question isn't of high quality. You *can* find the answer to your question on Google faster than it took you to type it out here. At any rate, I did answer your question below, if it helps, upvote or mark as answered.

Comment: Dear Chase Floral, I'm really sorry if you mark my question as stupid... I know how to use google, I just decided to post this question because i didn't find any satisfactory answer for me in google...

Comment: The difference is more clear with a folder than with a file. `Get-Item C:\folder` will get you the folder, and `Get-ChildItem c:\folder` will get you the items inside the folder. There is an overlap in their behaviour if you ask for one file. NB. that both work on PSProviders, not just drives, so the behavior might not overlap for using them to work with the registry or what have you.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler the example I used was in folders for that reason.

Comment: @G4rp I'm not one of the down-voters. I'm just trying to be helpful. I answered your question AND wrote an explanation as to why people are down-voting your question. I recognize that you're new to StackOverflow, so I'll give you the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Several months later, this question is the top result on Google, so you actually taking the time to improve and answer it is appreciated.

Answer (score 29):

**Get-Item**
Gets the item at the specified location.

```
Get-Item .\foo
# returns the item foo
```

**Get-ChildItem**
Gets the items and child items in one or more specified locations.

```
Get-ChildItem .\foo
# returns all of the children within foo
```

*note: Get-ChildItem can also recurse into the child directories*

```
Get-ChildItem .\foo -Recurse
# returns all of the children within foo AND the children of the children
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: how about when using -include in the get-item or get-childitem. when I use get-childitem -include *.txt no result is found when the expected result is more than 5

Comment: Explanation and examples are rather misleading, since one can think that Get-Item can be used for getting only one item.

Comment: But why does `(get-item $FilePath) -eq (get-childitem $FilePath)` return `False`?

Comment: @Teknowledgist That's because `-eq` doesn't test whether those two objects are equivalent.  Notice that `(get-item $FilePath) -eq (get-item $FilePath)` also returns false.  Try this instead: `Compare-Object (Get-Item $FilePath) (Get-ChildItem $FilePath) -IncludeEqual`

Comment: @rickyProgrammer I also have issues with -include and -exclude. My workaround is to just use -Filter, which seems to accomplish what I want anyways.

Answer (score 8):

If the you have a folder like this

```
Folder
├─ File-A
└─ File-B
```

- If the item is a folder, `Get-ChildItem` will return the child of the item.

```bsh
Get-Item Folder
# Folder

Get-ChildItem Folder
# File-A File-B
```

- If the item is not a folder, `Get-ChildItem` will return the item.

```bsh
Get-Item Folder\File-A
# File-A

Get-ChildItem Folder\File-A
# File-A
```

Answer (score 7):

Get the current directory

```
Get-Item .
```

Get all the items in the current directory

```
# use Get-Item
Get-Item *
# or use Get-ChildItem
Get-ChildItem
```

Get all txt files

```
# use Get-Item
Get-Item *.txt
# or use Get-ChildItem
Get-ChildItem *.txt
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Item?view=powershell-5.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem?view=powershell-5.1